# optional validation but requires on input

Tags: jquery, validation

I know this has probably been asked before, but I still can't find a solution to what I need.
I need to make a telephone number field optional (I know I can leave off the Required keyword) but if the user actually does enter data, I still need jQuery to work on the client side. I have tried all sorts of permutations and my last attempt was this:

```
    $("#telephone").rules("add", {
            required: false,
            pattern: "^\+?\d{10,14}|$"

        });
```

I'm probably way off, but if anyone could spare the time to point me in the right direction it will restore my faith in humanity ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526236/jquery-validator-plug-in-validate-optional-field here's a solution :)

Comment: Maybe it's just that I'm a noob, but I can't seem to get the example given above to work. Any other pointers woudl be gratefully received. thank you

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regular-expressions-in-javascript/ read this

Comment: Please go for Jquery Validation Plugin.
You can find similar question at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720753/how-to-use-jquery-validator-custom-method-on-optional-field-with-defaultvalue

Answer (score 1):

Please go for Jquery Validation Plugin.
You can find similar question at:
[How to use jQuery Validator custom method on optional field with defaultValue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720753/how-to-use-jquery-validator-custom-method-on-optional-field-with-defaultvalue)

[Running Example](http://jsfiddle.net/L3S9e/)

Copyright Andrew Whitaker for the fiddle.

```
$.validator.addMethod('phone', function (value, element) {
if (value != element.defaultValue) {  
    return this.optional(element) || /^[01]?[- .]?\(?[2-9]\d{2}\)?[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\d{4}$/.test(value);
} 
return true;
}, 'This is not a valid number');

$("#myForm").validate();
```

Comment: thanks for the response but this did not solve my problem. I am a junior dev trying to track down a validation bug in an application which is already in place. I have now discovereed that I needed a specific regex expression which allows an empty field or validates the field if not empty. I solved it with this regex  ^$|^\+?\d{10,14}$ where the regex allows empty ^$ or validates |^\+?\d{10,14}$ a number between 10 and 14 numbers. Thanks for your input though

Comment: @gettingThereSlowly no prob you're welcome.