# JQuery validation rule depends on another rule

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form where the required field is depend on another form field value. So the required rule may be true or false depend on the other field. The issue is accept rule should be there if only the required is true. How can I do that?

```
...,
fieldA: {
     maxlength: 3,
     accept: "[0-9]{3}",
     required: function() {
          if($('#fieldB').val() == 'ABCD') {
               return false;
          } else {
               return true;
          }
     }
},...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've written? it seems to implement the `dependency-callback` feature at https://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method

Comment: It's similar to the example there that makes parent required if age < 13.

Comment: @Barmar The issue with my current code is the accept rule is applying when required is false. I want the accept rule is to work only when required is true

Comment: You only made the `required` rule conditional on the other field. The `accept` rule is always applied.

Comment: Why do you have a regular expression in the `accept:` rule? It's supposed to contain a comma-separated list of MIME types to allow for a `file` input.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I need help on how can I achieve `accept` rule to apply when  required is true.

Comment: The problem is that you're confused about what the `accept` rule does. It's only for `type="file"`, and it's used to restrict the types of files that the user can upload. It's ignored for any other type of input.

Comment: If you want to match a regular expression, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785529/add-regex-to-jquery-validate

Comment: @Barmar I notice there is a custom rule added with the name `accept` in the code, which validate for regular expression.

Comment: The rule name caused a bit of confusion. I fixed the issue by editing the custom rule for checking whether element is optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize the 'accept' rule is a custom rule. I edited the code to check whether its an optional field. **this.optional(element)**

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("accept", function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.match(new RegExp("^" + param + "$"));
});
```

@Barmar Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is the right solution. The general pattern for writing custom rules should always include a `this.optional` check. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526236/jquery-validator-plug-in-validate-optional-field and all the examples at https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your `required` function will likely only get called when the form is rendered, and won't update the dependent field as the independent one changes. You could use a dymanic ui library like react or knockout, or you could simply bind a .change() handler to the independent field that manipulates the attributes of the other.

You could also bind something to .submit() that prevents submission if the configuration is not correct.

Comment: The dependency callback is supposed to run at the time when it's validating, not when the form is rendered.